Modal button click function not defined - Uncaught ReferenceError
Question Description:
I have a modal that should open when clicking on a "Share!" button on my webpage. However, I'm encountering an "Uncaught ReferenceError: openShareModal is not defined" error. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
Modal Code:
{% load static %}

<div id="shareModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content" id="{{ modal_id }}">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p class="centered-text form-labels">Broadcast the {{ modal_card_title }} Card</p>
        <div class="social-media-button-container">
            <!-- Social media buttons -->
        </div>
        <input type="text" value="https://www.example.com/system_page" id="shareLink" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>    

<script defer>
    var modal = document.getElementById("shareModal");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    function openShareModal(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function shareOnFacebook(shareUrl) {
        // Share on Facebook code
    }

    function shareOnX(shareUrl) {
        // Share on X code
    }

    function shareOnInstagram(shareUrl) {
        // Share on Instagram code
    }

    function shareOnLinkedIn(shareUrl) {
        // Share on LinkedIn code
    }
</script>

Individual Page Code:
{% extends 'home1/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
<body id="background_image_mohadino">
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <!-- Content details -->
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <!-- Share button -->
            <button class="mohadino_button btn btn-custom btn-lg w-75" type="button" onclick="openShareModal()">Share!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The Share Modal -->
    {%
    include 'cards2/share_modal.html' with
    modal_id='background-image-modal-mohadino'
    modal_card_title='Raven'
    share_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/cards/mohadino/'
    %}
</body>
{% endblock %}

Error Message:
mohadino/:120 Uncaught ReferenceError: openShareModal is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (mohadino/:120:129)

I've tried several approaches, including moving the script to the bottom of the body and using the defer attribute. However, I'm still facing the same issue. The modal should open when clicking the "Share!" button, but it seems the openShareModal function is not recognized.
Any insights on why this function is not being recognized and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

are you sure the file cards2/share_modal.html is being included? add some <div>hello</div> at the top of file to verify
